# Does a HP MDS600 fit in a HP 10636 G2 rack?

Tags: storage, hp, rack, rackmount

In the Quick Installation Giide to the MDS600/D6000 storage server it says

> IMPORTANT: Some racks other than the HP Rack 10000 Series rack do not
>   allow full access to hard drive bays 29-35 in hard drive drawer 2.

I have a HP 10636 G2 19" Rack 36U (PN: AF011A).

**Question**

It is temping to think that the rack is supported, but can anyone comfirm that 10000 Series to HP means 10xxx, so my rack is supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your rack, the [10636 G2](https://h10057.www1.hp.com/ecomcat/hpcatalog/specs/provisioner/05/AF011A.htm), is part of the [HP 10000 G2 rack series](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12402_na/12402_na.pdf).

10000-series includes the 10614, 10622, 10636, 10642, etc.

In addition, the MDS600 storage enclosure will fit.